# What happend when i allocate str = (char *) malloc(1); and copy a string to str

Tags: c, malloc

When I allocate memory for array in C, I try to use Malloc and just use 1 byte.
`str = (char *) malloc(1);` after that I copy a string `"How the memory works"` to `str`.
So surprise then `str` can save `How the memory works`. Before I run the program I guess this will be overflow memory :( . Can you explain why `str` can store data more than 1 byte? May the program auto `realloc` ?

Comment: Writing to invalid memory is undefined behaviour. UB means it may appear to "work", or it may crash, or it may produce wrong results or any other behaviour.

Comment: What makes you think you did not overflow the allocated memory?

Comment: I think it will be an overflow memory. But I don't understand why "How the memory works" can store or I lucky when it works

Comment: `malloc` returns a memory address. The memory is a huge collection of bytes that are accessible by address. It's like checking into a hotel, asking for 3 consecutive rooms. You get the keys to rooms 503, 504 and 505. So you go the fifth floor, and are surprised that there is a hallway with at least twenty rooms. If you try to go into room 506, you may or may not succeed, you may walk into a naked guest, you may get thrown out.